# Having Issues with SUM in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, select, sum

I have three tables `Match_Event`, `Team_Detail` and `Match_Schedule`.

The `Match_Schedule` has columns `MatchId`, `Hometeam_Id`, `Away TeamId`:

```
matchId  HTeam  Ateam
----------------------
  123     -1      -7 
  231     -3      -5
```

The `Match_event` has things related to that Match. (Gaol, Foul. etc)

```
matchId    TeamId    Score
--------------------------------
  123         1         1    
  123         1         1  
  123         7         1    
  231         5         1
```

And the last table (`TeamDetail`)

```
 TeamId    TeamName
   123     USA
   231     Uk
```

I have tried this

```
SELECT      
    Team_Detail.Team_Name,  
    SUM(CASE WHEN Team_Detail.Serno = Match_Events.Team_Id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS HomeTeamScore, 
    Team_Detail.Team_Name, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN Team_Detail.Serno = Match_Events.Team_Id THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS AwayTeamScore              
FROM         
    Match_Schedule  
INNER JOIN 
    Match_Events ON Match_Schedule.Match_Serno = Match_Events.Match_ID   
INNER JOIN
    Team_Detail ON Match_Events.Team_Id = Team_Detail.Serno 
GROUP BY 
    Team_Name, Team_Name
```

and I get the correct result but one above the other rather than in the same line.

Can some one please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some missing information here- I see in your query you reference columns named *Serno*, but they are not specified in your table definitions above.

It also looks as if you are mixing up matchID and TeamID in your example data (I see matches and teams both with IDs of 123 and 231).

I think you probably want to join against the Team_Detail table twice. Once where the tables is aliased as HomeTeam (or something similar) and joins against Match_Schedule only for the home team.

Then the same thing for the away team.

Something like this:

```
SELECT  HomeTeam.Team_Name AS HomeTeamName, AwayTeam.Team_Name AS AwayTeamName, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN HomeTeam.TeamID = Match_Events.TeamId THEN Score ELSE 0 END) AS HomeTeamScore,
        SUM(CASE WHEN AwayTeam.TeamID = Match_Events.TeamId THEN Score ELSE 0 END) AS AwayTeamScore
FROM    Match_Schedule
JOIN    Match_Events ON Match_Events.MatchID = Match_Schedule.MatchID
JOIN    Team_Detail AS HomeTeam ON HomeTeam.TeamID = Match_Schedule.HTeam
JOIN    Team_Detail AS AwayTeam ON AwayTeam.TeamID = Match_Schedule.ATeam
GROUP BY HomeTeam.Team_Name, AwayTeam.Team_Name
```

Also, I think yo uwant to SUM based on Score, rather than a hard coded 1 value.... Unless maybe a team's score is always 1 (indicating a win, perhaps).

Answer (score 0):

If you want information about a single match to be on a single row, then you should aggregate by the `MatchId`.  Then use conditional aggregation to get the information you are looking for.

```
SELECT max(case when ms.hteam = td.TeamId then Team_Detail.Team_Name end) as hometeam,  
       SUM(CASE WHEN ms.hteam = td.TeamId THEN me.score ELSE 0 END) AS HomeTeamScore, 
       max(case when ms.ateam = td.TeamId then Team_Detail.Team_Name end) as awayteam, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN ms.hteam = td.TeamId THEN me.score ELSE 0 END) AS AwayTeamScore              
FROM Match_Schedule ms INNER JOIN 
     Match_Events me
     ON ms.matchId = me.matchID INNER JOIN
     Team_Detail td
     ON me.teamId = td.teamId 
GROUP BY ms.matchid;
```

Note some other things.  I changed the query to use the fields based on the description in the question, rather than the example in your query.  I also updated the calculation to use the `score` field, rather than just counting `1`.